# How to find probability of drawing ball from a given container?

Tags: c++, algorithm, probability, combinatorics

A container having 2 balls, one is red and second one is black.
One ball is drawn each time and placed again in the container.Drawing of ball is done `n`times where `1<=n<=10^6`.I want to find out the probability of drawing red ball at least `r`where `0<=r<=n`.For example, let `n=3`and `r=2`then probability `p`can be calculated as :

```
p=( C(3,2)+C(3,3) ) / (2^3)
p=(3+1)/8
p=0.5
```

where `C(n,r) = n!/(n-r)!r!`.
It can also be solved using binomial distribution.
But, it is difficult to calculate for given `n`and `r`.

Comment: You already know the formula: C(n,r) = n!/(n-r)!r!, why it's difficult ? you don't know how to code factorial function ?

Comment: @algojava But,it is very difficult for given value of n and r

Comment: because n can be 10^6 ? if the difference between n and r is small, I can help you to write the efficient code to calculate binomial distribution.

Comment: @Enigma I don't understand what you think is hard given `n` and `r`. If you have required bounds for `n` and `r` just check them with an `if` statement.

Comment: ya, n can be 10^6 also r can be from 0 to 10^6.So difference is not so small.

Comment: @jeffreyhaines for given n and r ,how to calculate?

Comment: it's better to use Π form of formula instead of factorial, to cut off repeated and unused operations. e.g.  n!/(n-r)! = (n-r+1)(n-r+2)...n

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try using *logarithms*, i.e. instead of

```
 P(r, n) = n! / ((n-r)! * r! * r**n)
```

compute just

```
 log(P(r, r)) = log(n!) - log((n-r)!) - log(r!) - r*log(n)
```

All factorials are easy computable as logarithms:

```
 log(n!) = log(n) + log(n - 1) + ... + log(2) + log(1)
```

When obtain `log(P(r, n))` all you have to do is to exponentiate. As a further improvement you can use [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation) for the factorials in case `n` is large:

```
 n! ~ (n / e)**n * sqrt(2 * PI * n)
```

so (`ln` stands for the natural logarithm)

```
 ln(n!) ~ n * ln(n) - n - ln(n)/2 - ln(2 * PI)/2
```

**Edit**: If you are looking for **CDF** (*Cumulative Distribution Function*, probability that random value is less or equal given `x`), it can be represented as *regularized imcomplete beta function*:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution

```
P(x <= k) = I(1 - p, n - r, r+1)
p = 1/2 in your case
```

in case C++, the implementation can be found in [Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/libs/math/doc/sf_and_dist/html/math_toolkit/special/sf_beta/ibeta_function.html)

Comment: ooh, neat, then can use just exp() function

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of converting to logarithms. How is adding logarithms any faster than just multiplying the numbers directly?

Comment: @ruakh: logarithms actually *slow down* the implmentation, but allow you to work with *large numbers*: `1e6! == 8.2639...e5565708` is definitely an *overflow* when multiplying numbers, but a reasonable value when adding up logarithms: `ln(1e6!) == 12815518.38...`

Comment: Very interesting. One remark though, I don't really get your formula, there are only one red ball and one black ball.

Comment: @L. Meyer: Since we return the ball after each test, the procedure itself is equal to simple *Bernoulli scheme* with `p = 1/2` (fair coin tossing)

Comment: `P(2, 3)` gives 0.375 instead of 0.5 or I did something wrong?

Comment: @L. Meyer: you, probably, want not density but **CDF** which is `0.375 + 0.125 == 0.5`;